# Bootstrap image resize for small screen, not working

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, resize

I am trying to resize image using Bootstrap. I have a sufficiently large logo, for large screens & resolutions. Apparently, the image should resize well in all resolutions (small & big resolutions).
I have used the Bootstrap’s .img-responsive class for making images responsive. As is evident, image shows fine in large resolutions, but the image should become small in smaller resolutions. The problem is that - image is not getting smaller in smaller resolutions.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<BODY>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="navbar-header col-xs-3 col-md-3"> 
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                   <img class="img-responsive" src="someimage.png">
               </a> 
           </div> 
           <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9"> 
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
                   <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="A1.png"></a></li> 
                   <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="A2.png"></a></li> 
               </ul> 
           </div> 
         </div> 
    </nav> 
</BODY>
```

Comment: Put the img tag anywhere you like, a NAV or DIV (container), results should be the same. <img class="img-responsive" src="someimage.png">

Comment: I guess your problem is with the parent element. Please provide some code for us or better create an example bootply with your problem. Without this it's hard to help you.

Comment: You can also view it here http://www.enterhelix.com/new/  So you can see that the images are not shrinking or expanding with resolution. They always remain the same.

Comment: Next time please add your code to your question via the `edit` function. I tried your example code, it works fine for me (http://www.bootply.com/TmSwClXC1Y). Your problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: So what's the problem? The Logo resizes for me perfectly on your enterhelix.com/new site..

Comment: Code is perfectly fine. But you can see that the images are not resizing (i.e, they are not shrinking or expanding with resolution change)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57159/discussion-between-sebsemillia-and-user2554706).

Answer (score 7):

I think the root of your problem is that you are expecting that the .img-responsive class will automatically make your images smaller for smaller screens, and this isn't exactly how it works.

It actually applies  max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image, i.e. if it's a wide image it won't be wider than its parent. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that is what I exactly expect. So, to make it small for smaller resolutions, what should I do?
Do I have to use my own media-queries i.e., different images for different resolutions.

Comment: @user2554706, yes media-queries would be one option. The challenge might be that as the bootstrap grid changes or collapses, the width of the image parents will change and so you'll need multiple rules to allow for the window or viewport width, as well as the specifics of your images. I played with one idea if it's any use to you: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/DxzJA  ... good luck!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what, I am thinking. I have to write multiple rules. I wonder, Bootstrap being so popular and why they did not address this very common thing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you possibly answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709760/bootstrap-typography-and-font-size-doe-not-change

Comment: @user2554706 > why they did not address this very common thing? .. Bootstrap can be a fantastic time saver but it's not the only horse in town. There are many other good options and they all have their strenghts and differences and you might prefer one over the other. If you haven't already, some others you could look at are http://foundation.zurb.com or http://www.getskeleton.com . They are all good ;)

Answer (score 3):

With bootstrap 4 there are display utilities which can be used to render different images for different viewport,

e.g.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header col-xs-3 col-md-3"> 
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
               <img class="d-none d-sm-block" src="someimage.png"><!-- Image to show on screens from small to extra large -->
               <img class="d-sm-none" src="someimagesmaller.png"><!-- Image to show on extra small screen (mobile portrait) -->
           </a> 
       </div> 
     </div> 
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header col-xs-3 col-md-3"> 
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
               <img class="hidden-xs" src="someimage.png">
<img class="visible-xs" src="someimagesmaller.png">
           </a> 
       </div> 
       <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9"> 
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
               <li><a href="#"><img class="hidden-xs" src="A1.png">
  <img class="visible-xs" src="A1smaller.png"></a></li> 
        <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="A2.png"> </a></li> 
           </ul> 
       </div> 
     </div> 
   </nav>  `
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap version 4 class ".img-responsive" has been changed to ".img-fluid".

Answer (score -3):

use the class="img-responsive" and it will shrink the image when you open in mobile or other device using bootstrap css. but for u its not working can u check the correct links you added in the headers.